# Method that creates new array on every call?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method that creates a new array with a recognizable name every time that it's called. It's supposed to create arrays of size 2 that store two double values inside.

```
public static double[] newarray(double x, double y) {
    double a[] = new double[2];
    a[0] = x;
    a[1] = y;
}
```

Basically something like this, but I would like the name of the array to be variable so that I can create multiple arrays like this with the same function.

For example the first array would be a, the next a1, a2, a3 and so forth.

Comment: Arrays don't have a name, variables do, but they won't help you here (if you're not thinking about something like `a = newarray(....); a1 = newarray(...);`).

Comment: You don't understand something important (not sure what exactly, possibly the difference between fields and variables) - this question does not make sense.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was poorly formulated and ended up confusing you, I am very new to programming. I think I am able to work out my problem with suggestions provided by other users though. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the function like this:

```
public static double[] newArray(double x, double y) {
    return new double[]{x, y};
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
double[] myArray1 = newArray(10d, 20d);
double[] myArray2 = newArray(3d, 4d);
```

Answer (score 1):

> so that I can create multiple arrays like this with the same function

You already can.

Add this line to the end of your `newarray()` function:

```
return a;
```

Now observe that *a variety* of consumers can invoke the same function.

```
double a1[] = newarray(0,1);
double a2[] = newarray(2,3);
System.out.printf("%f\n", a1[0]); // prints 0, as required
```

Notice how creating the array `a2` does not replace the existing array `a1` in anyway.

So we see that *the same function `newarray()`* can be invoked many times, returning by value a reference to a *separate* array each time.

---

I acknowledge that *inside* `newArray()`, the variable name `a` will be re-used each time. But since it is *not* a member variable, nor is it a static variable: its state is lost *every time the function exits*. It will **not** re-use the same memory on subsequent invocations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want different names for arrays would have your reasons for it, maybe using an HashMap structure help to accomplish this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, double[]> arrays = new HashMap<>();
        String name = "a";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            arrays.put(name + i, newarray(23, 43));
        }
    }

    public static double[] newarray(double x, double y) {
        double[] a = new double[2];
        a[0] = x;
        a[1] = y;
        return a;
    }
```

Hope this help